# How to pass epoch and batch size when using label powerset in keras

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, multilabel-classification, scikit-multilearn

I have a multi-label problem and with some research, I was able to use Label powerset in conjunction with ML algorithms. Now I want to use the Label powerset with neural network and as per the [official website](http://scikit.ml/multilabeldnn.html) I can use Label powerset. But I am not able to understand how to modify my existing code to be able to use Label Powerset.

I want to know how can we pass epoch or batch_size or any other parameter passed in the fit function of the model.

Since I have a multi-label problem I have used MultiLabelBinarizer of sklearn so my each target row looks like this [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].

and lastly, if someone could explain to me what is KERAS_PARAMS and Keras() in the below line:

```
def create_model_multiclass(input_dim, output_dim):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=input_dim, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
clf = LabelPowerset(classifier=Keras(create_model_multiclass, True, KERAS_PARAMS), require_dense=[True,True])
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Below is my existing neural network code

```
cnn_model = Sequential()
cnn_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn_model.add(Conv1D(25,7,activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPool1D(2))
cnn_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
cnn_model.add(Conv1D(25,7,activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPool1D(2))
cnn_model.add(Flatten())
cnn_model.add(Dense(25,activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(Dense(12,activation='softmax'))
cnn_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
history = cnn_model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), batch_size=32, epochs=180,verbose=1)
plot_history(history)
predictions = cnn_model.predict(X_test)
```

I want my output row to look like this only [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] as later I will use my MultiLabelBinarizer for the inverse transform of this.

Answer (score 1):

`KERAS_PARAMS` are parameters to the Keras scikit [wrapper](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/). The documentation for it is rather sparse.

Basically it seems to be the params that you would pass, for instance, to `keras.fit`.

```
KERAS_PARAMS = dict(epochs=10, batch_size=100, verbose=0)
```

From reading the docs, it seems to me that `LabelPowerset` transforms a multi-label problem into a multi-class problem by creating class permutations. You may consider just using a native Keras solution for a multi-label problem rather than using a wrapper.

The following tutorial seems reasonable:
https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/multi-label-image-classification-tutorial-with-keras-imagedatagenerator-cd541f8eaf24

The key differences are that your output layer should have a `sigmoid` activation rather than `softmax` and the loss should be `binary_crossentrophy` rather than categorical.

Comment: The thing is LabelPowerset makes the combinations of all the different classes and those combinations become one class making the problem from Multi-Label to Multi-Class so, wouldn't it be significant to use softmax for the multi-class problem with loss as categorical_crossentropy?

Comment: Suppose you have three classes A, B, C. And the end goal is to be able to have a multi-label classification where you get a probability of these classes being present. This can be achieve with Keras directly using 'sigmoid' activation / binary_crossentrophy loss. Or you can have LabelPowerset create artificial classes with each set permutation e.g. Empty, A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC and use a Keras multi-class model (softmax / categorical_crossentrophy). To me it would seem that the first approach is preferable.

Comment: In case anyone wonders what is Keras(). It is a MEKA wrapper and if you get are not sure how to use is
just use this line
```
from skmultilearn.ext import Keras
```